# Website Hosting Issues

Tags: web, dns, hosting, web-hosting, hostmonster

I have an issue going on with my website and it is quite strange. I did an activity of revamping my website. After updating the files, am not able to open the website on company network. The website  name is:

```
http://www.ffbl.com
```

This website does not open on my company network sayn err_name not resolved When i ping the website in cmd i get the ip address as:

```
http://74.220.215.203
```

But when i write the same ip address in the browser it says there is no website configured at this address. The website is hosted on hostmonster.com. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: check your domain nameserver

Comment: could u be a little descriptive??

Comment: [try this link](https://www.123-reg.co.uk/support/answers/Domains-Archive/Domain-Configuration/how-do-i-point-my-domain-name-to-an-ip-address-1200/) or tell me about you domain purchasing site. is it godaddy or other

Answer (score 0):

The domain http://www.ffbl.com is loading fine for me, so I believe your IP address blocked in the server. You can get your IP address from the URL  https://www.whatismyip.com/ and check it with hostmonster.

> > > But when i write the same ip address in the browser it says there is no website configured at this address.

I think the given IP address is server main shared IP address so it will show a default page.

Comment: The server at ffbl.com can't be found, because the DNS lookup failed. DNS is the network service that translates a website's name to its Internet address. This error is most often caused by having no connection to the Internet or a misconfigured network. It can also be caused by an unresponsive DNS server or a firewall preventing Google Chrome from accessing the network.

Comment: that is what am getting

Comment: Could you access all other sites other than ffbl.com ? if yes then  your IP address should be blocked in the server firewall as I suggested earlier please check it with hostmonster.